# OR condition jQuery to target two different elements on mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use an `OR` condition in jQuery for a `mousedown` event? Currently my code looks like this but it isn't working.

```
$('#draggable-one' || '#draggable-two').on('mousedown', function () {
     //do stuff
}
```

Comment: You clearly didn't bother to go to the jQuery manual and read how their selectors work

Comment: @charlietfl i actually did search for it on the jQuery manual, but didn't know exactly what to look for. i didn't find that page unfortuantely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass selector separated by `,` [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('#draggable-one, #draggable-two').on('mousedown', function () {
     //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the mousedown in both just do it like this

```
$('#draggable-one, #draggable-two').on('mousedown', function () {
     //do stuff
}
```

More info on [jQuery Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)